# How to set default value of select list field on add node form?

Tags: nodes, forms

I am trying to set the default value of a select list field on a node add form. The field name attribute in the HTML of the form is:

```
field_state[und]
```

The ID of the add form is:

```
local-affiliate-node-form
```

I created a little module to try to do this. It just has this code in it:

```
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == 'local-affiliate-node-form'){
        $form['field_state']['und']['#value'] = 17;
    }
}
```

I enabled the module and cleared cache but it doesn't appear to work. I also tried these lines inside the IF statement:

```
$form['field_state']['und']['value'] = 17;
$form['field_state']['und']['value']['#value'] = 17;
$form['field_state']['und']['#default_value'] = 17;
```

In case you're wondering, I can't use the Drupal interface to set the default value because eventually that "17" will be dynamic, so it will change depending on what the user clicks and I will use a string in the URL in place of a static number.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The form ID uses `_`, not `-`

Comment: Wow...rookie mistake! Thanks a lot Clive! If you post as a response I can mark it as the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you need "code" way you need set default value like this.

```
$form['field_name']['und']['#default_value'][0] = "1"
```

"1" -  its number of element which you want set default.

I use that when i need set programaticaly default value for field which use term reference.